# Extract heart rate from heartbeats '*.wav' format in specific window frame (like 15 seconds) in Python

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, signals, librosa, waveform

How can I extract heart rate from heartbeats sound in "*.wav" format in Python.

Comment: Do you have some example audio? Is it recorded with a stethoscope or some other method?

Comment: @JonNordby I'm not sure how can I upload the audio file here. yes, it's recorded with a stethoscope. It's a 10 min heartbeat sound and I need to extract the peak in some rolling window.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to apply a peak detection algorithm over your audio file.

```
import librosa  

y, sr = librosa.load(<path/to/audio.wav>, duration=15)
onset_env = librosa.onset.onset_strength(y=y, sr=sr,
                                         hop_length=512,
                                         aggregate=np.median)
peaks = librosa.util.peak_pick(onset_env, 3, 3, 3, 5, 0.5, 10)
```

You can then plot it as well like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
times = librosa.frames_to_time(np.arange(len(onset_env)),
                               sr=sr, hop_length=512)
plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
D = librosa.stft(y)
librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(D, ref=np.max),
                         y_axis='log', x_axis='time')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1, sharex=ax)
plt.plot(times, onset_env, alpha=0.8, label='Onset strength')
plt.vlines(times[peaks], 0,
           onset_env.max(), color='r', alpha=0.8,
           label='Selected peaks')
plt.legend(frameon=True, framealpha=0.8)
plt.axis('tight')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This answer is based on the librosa documentation given [here](https://librosa.org/doc/0.7.0/generated/librosa.util.peak_pick.html).